# Ext.data.Connection.override request

Tags: ajax, extjs, request, overriding

I am trying to intercept all requests, before send, from an Extjs App, POST and GET and then manipulate the URL and add a new Header, Authorization: Bearer XYZ123.

I've this code:

```
Ext.data.Connection.override({

    request: function (options) {
        var me = this;

        this.cors = true;
        this.useDefaultHeader = false;
        this.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;

        options.headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer VAROIS1iOiJKV1QiLCJh" };

        var separator = options.url.indexOf('/') == 0 ? "" : "/";
        options.url = UrlAPIPrefix + separator + options.url;

        return me.callOverridden(arguments);
    }
});
```

But when i try to use it, the Header Authorization is not sent in both cases, GET and POST. Parameters are not sent when using POST. I am able to see params if debugging the code into Extjs files, but can't see it on chrome Request Headers, see image.

[image]

If any one knows how to do it, in one place, i will be glad if you can help me.

Comment: hello there, Thanks for both replies. You guys are correct. I end up with mix of both solutions. Also a had to change my global.asax, on my .net mvc app adding:

Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) setting headers, Cache-Control, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Max-Age in case of HttpMethod == "OPTIONS"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `Ext.Ajax` - the singleton of `Ext.data.Connection` - is used for most requests in the framework and overriding the latter does not affect the former. This overriding behavior was changed in extjs 5 and is intended by Sencha.

Use what you need of this instead:

```
Ext.Ajax.setWithCredentials(true);
Ext.Ajax.on({
    beforerequest: function(conn, options) {
        options.headers = options.headers || {};
        options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer VAROIS1iOiJKV1QiLCJh';
    },
    requestexception: function(conn, response, options) {
        Ext.Error.raise('...');
    }
});
```

And don't hardcode the token into your javascript!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the class, i created a bootstrap class to set up the ajax interceptor. Called Bootstrap.init() in Application.launch() method.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Bootstrap', {

    singleton : true,

    init: function() {
        Ext.Ajax.on({
            beforerequest: function(conn, opts){
                if(opts.url && Ext.String.startsWith(opts.url, '/')) {
                    return;
                }
                if(opts.url && !Ext.String.startsWith(opts.url, MyApp.Config.SERVER_CONTEXT)) {
                    opts.url = MyApp.Config.SERVER_CONTEXT + opts.url;
                }
                var clientId = MyApp.getApplication().clientId;
                opts.headers = Ext.apply({'X-Client-Id': clientId}, opts.headers);
                Ext.log('Sending Request to : ', opts.url);
            }
        });
    }
});
```